# How is it possible that tor is using 4 nodes instead of three? Is my secur

Tags: node

How is it possible that tor is using 4 nodes instead of three?  Has tor been modified or is my security under threat

Comment: Where are you seeing 4 nodes being used?

Comment: @pastly I've edited and added a picture

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, Tor will make 4-hop circuits because extending a circuit 1 more hop is cheaper than building an entirely new one.

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/path-spec.txt search for cannibalize